# About NotchFilter,Filter is not completely

Tags: audio, filter

I try to use music NotchFilter filter specific Hertz, but to filter is not complete.
The Library I use is:(ddf.minim.effects.NotchFilter)
https://github.com/DASAR/Minim-Android

I try to filter out the part of the 3000-7000 hz,I save the filtered audio, using software to analyze the audio, found 3000-7000 hz has not been completely filtered out (Only a small part of the filter)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W72Sq.jpg)

my code：

```
final int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            minBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

notchLeft = new NotchFilter(5000, 4000,44100);
notchRight = new NotchFilter(5000, 4000,44100);
```

.....

```
float[][] signals = deinterleaveData(shortToFloat(buffer), 2);
                    if(isFilterLeft) {
                        notchLeft.process(signals[0]);
                    }
                    if(isFilterRight) {
                        notchRight.process(signals[1]);
                    }
                    float[] newBuffer = interleaveData(signals);

                    if (buffer.length < newBuffer.length)
                        buffer = new short[newBuffer.length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < newBuffer.length; i++)
                        buffer[i] = (short) (newBuffer[i] * Short.MAX_VALUE);
```

...........

```
private float[] shortToFloat(short[] audio) {

        float[] converted = new float[audio.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < converted.length; i++) {
            // [-3276,32768] -> [-1,1]
            converted[i] = audio[i] / 32768f;
        }

        return converted;
    }

    float[][] deinterleaveData(float[] samples, int numChannels) {
        // assert(samples.length() % numChannels == 0);
        int numFrames = samples.length / numChannels;

        float[][] result = new float[numChannels][];
        for (int ch = 0; ch < numChannels; ch++) {
            result[ch] = new float[numFrames];
            for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
                result[ch][i] = samples[numChannels * i + ch];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    float[] interleaveData(float[][] data) {
        int numChannels = data.length;
        int numFrames = data[0].length;

        float[] result = new float[numFrames * numChannels];
        for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
            for (int ch = 0; ch < numChannels; ch++) {
                result[numChannels * i + ch] = data[ch][i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I put the audio data is split into two channels, filtering respectively, then together.
I'm not sure what's wrong.Do you know what could be a problem?